# Child components in Angular not recognized in Storybook while working perfectly fine with ng serve

Tags: angular, typescript, storybook

I'm building some components in Angular using Storybook which so far has been working.  I just came to a component where I nest another component inside of it and it's not iterating in Storybook.  When I look in the console I see an error telling me to make sure the child component is added to the module because it doesn't recognize it.  I scratched my head for some time about this checking my code and couldn't find the problem.  I decided to run `ng serve` and go to `localhost://4200` to see what happens and everything works as expected without the error.  I looked over the documentation at Storybook's site and I don't see anything exhibiting a special way to handle components with child components so I don't understand what's happening.  Here's some of my code,

**Child Component's Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BoxSizeVisualizerComponent } from './box-size-visualizer.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [BoxSizeVisualizerComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports:[CommonModule, BoxSizeVisualizerComponent],
  bootstrap:[BoxSizeVisualizerComponent]
})
export class BoxSizeVisualizerModule { }
```

**Parent Component's Module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BoxSizeFrameComponent } from './box-size-frame.component';
import { BoxSizeVisualizerModule } from '../box-size-visualizer/box-size-visualizer.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [ BoxSizeFrameComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BoxSizeVisualizerModule
  ],
  exports:[CommonModule, BoxSizeVisualizerModule, BoxSizeFrameComponent],
  bootstrap:[BoxSizeFrameComponent]
})
export class BoxSizeFrameModule { }
```

**The Story File**

```
import { Meta, Story } from "@storybook/angular/types-6-0";
import { boxSizeParams, boxSizeSize } from "../box-size-visualizer/box-size-visualizer.component";
import { BoxSizeFrameComponent } from "./box-size-frame.component";


export default{
    title: 'Demo Frames/Box Size Frame',
    component: BoxSizeFrameComponent
} as Meta;

const Sizes: boxSizeParams[] = [*/a bunch of objects/*]

const Template: Story<BoxSizeFrameComponent> = (args:BoxSizeFrameComponent)=>({props:args});

export const Primary = Template.bind({});

Primary.args = ({Sizes:Sizes});
```

As I said before I'm not having any problems with using `ng serve` so I'm just putting some code here for the sake of following standard so if you need to see something else let me know and I'll add it.  Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok something told me to look through the Storybook example components and I saw in the `Header` that they use the `Button` component.  In the Header's story I saw they defined a `decorators` array in their default export like this

```
export default {
  title: 'Example/Header',
  component: Header,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      declarations: [Button],
      imports: [CommonModule],
    }),
  ],
} as Meta;
```

So I modified my code to this

```
export default{
    title: 'Demo Frames/Box Size Frame',
    component: BoxSizeFrameComponent,
    decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
            imports:[CommonModule, BoxSizeVisualizerModule]
        })
    ]
} as Meta;
```

Everything works now :)